# Read will loop end of file

Tags: c, io

I'm writing a C code that will read content of file and output it on the terminal.
This is my code so far:

```
rdfd = open(address, O_RDONLY);
read(rdfd, reader, 1);
while(rdfd != 0){ //will end if EOF is reached
    for(x=0; x<1; x++) printf("%c", reader[x]); //for printing at the terminal
    read(rdfd,reader,1);
}
```

Now, for an example, I have an `index.html` file with the ff content:

```
<html>
    <body><h1>HELLO WORLD</h1></body>
</html>
```

The program will print something like this:

```
<html>
    <body><h1>HELLO WORLD</h1></body>
</html>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> (...)
```

The `>` will just go on infinitely. I don't know why. Was there something wrong with the while condition?

Comment: try replacing `while(rdfd != 0)` with `while(!feof(rdfd))`

Comment: You are checking if the descriptor is 0. But the descriptor is valid (not zero) and hence the last character read will be printed repeatedly..

Comment: @Abbath feof(rdfd) will either return a warning or be a compiler error like this `passing argument 1 of ‘feof’ makes pointer from integer without a cast'

Comment: @SantoshA You are right there, open returns an int whereas feof expects a file pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rdfd is the File Descriptor of the file you are reading from. Testing it for zero (`while(rdfd != 0)` actually doesn't do anything useful. If you want to test whether the file was opened correctly (you should) test if for < 0.

If you want to know when the end of the file is reached, check the return value from the *read* call, i.e:

```
int bytesRead = read(rdfd, reader, 1);

while (bytesRead > 0)
{ ... 
  bytesRead = read(rdfd,reader,1);
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much! Everything makes sense now.